# John has 13 balls less than Peter, and they have 31 balls between them. How many has each of them?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Word problem involving use if symbols

Comment: The usual approach is to set some variables (one for John, one for Peter), then write out the given information algebraically, using those variables, and solve.  In this case, of course, trial and error would also work just fine.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receives responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @Yemi Are you saying you are unable to solve the puzzle? Or are you asking how to "solve it mathematically"?

Comment: Denote by $J$ the amount of balls John has; in the same manner, denote by $P$ the amount of balls Peter has. If $J$ (John) has $13$ balls less than $P$ (Peter), it would follow then that $J=P-13$, i.e. $13=P-J$. You are also given the information that both $J$ and $P$ have $31$ balls between them; this is to say, $J+P=31$. To compare, $$\begin{align} P-J &= 13 \\ P+J &= 31\end{align}$$ Now what things would imply were you to subtract $13$ from $31$?

Comment: or just (2p-13)=31; 2p=44; p=22; p-13=9; 22+9=31;

Answer (score 1):

Well if John has 13 balls less than Peter, then if $J$ is John's balls and $P$ is Peter's, we get
$J=P-13$

But then the total balls are $31$, that is $J+P=31$

We then make the substitution from the first line so:
$(P-13)+P=31$